# No webpage was found for the web address: http://localhost:8080 in Spring boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I've started my Spring boot application, and the applicaiton has started when I see the console, but when I try to open the browser to run, it shows No webpage was found for the web address: http://localhost:8080/Demo/login.html. What is the problem here? Here is my code

```
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication .class, args);
    }

}
```

My login.html is available under

```
src/main/resources/templates/login.html
```

Here is the pom.xml

```
<properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
    <resources>
         <resource>
            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            <filtering>true</filtering>
        </resource>
    </resources>
</build>
```

Log it shows clearly as Tomcat server started at 8080 port number

```
 2018-12-19 17:02:24.213  INFO 709136 --- [           main] 
com.test.demo.DemoApplication          : Starting DemoApplication on Test with PID 709136 (C:\Users\Syed\Documents\DEMO\DEMO\target\classes started by Syed in C:\Users\Syed\Documents\DEMO\DEMO)
 2018-12-19 17:02:24.254  INFO 709136 --- [           main] 
 com.test.demo.DemoApplication          : The following profiles are active: @spring.profiles.active@
2018-12-19 17:02:25.674  INFO 709136 --- [           main] 
o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2018-12-19 17:02:25.705  INFO 709136 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2018-12-19 17:02:25.706  INFO 709136 --- [           main] 
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/9.0.13
2018-12-19 17:02:25.715  INFO 709136 --- [           main] 
o.a.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener   : The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: [C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_45\bin;C:\Windows\Sun\Java\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_45/bin/../jre/bin/server;C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_45/bin/../jre/bin;C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_45/bin/../jre/lib/amd64;C:\Program Files (x86)\RSA SecurID Token Common;C:\Program Files\RSA SecurID Token Common;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Citrix\System32\;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\McAfee\Solidcore\Tools\GatherInfo;C:\Program Files\McAfee\Solidcore\Tools\Scanalyzer;C:\Program Files\McAfee\Solidcore\;C:\Program Files\McAfee\Solidcore\Tools\ScGetCerts;C:\Program Files\Citrix\System32\;C:\Program Files\Citrix\ICAService\;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Hitachi ID\;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_45\bin;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_45\jre\bin;C:\Users\AF68935\AppData\Roaming\npm;C:\Users\AF68935\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\bin;;C:\Users\AF68935\Downloads\spring-tool-suite-4-4.0.2.RELEASE-e4.9.0-win32.win32.x86_64\sts-4.0.2.RELEASE;;.]
2018-12-19 17:02:25.837  INFO 709136 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
 2018-12-19 17:02:25.837  INFO 709136 --- [           main] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 1510 ms
2018-12-19 17:02:26.214  INFO 709136 --- [           main] o.s.s.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor  : Initializing ExecutorService 'applicationTaskExecutor'
2018-12-19 17:02:26.523  INFO 709136 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http) with context path ''
2018-12-19 17:02:26.542  INFO 709136 --- [           main] com.test.demo.DemoApplication          : Started DemoApplication in 2.95 seconds (JVM running for 3.852)
2018-12-19 17:04:35.175  INFO 709136 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring DispatcherServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
```

2018-12-19 17:04:35.175  INFO 709136 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Initializing Servlet 'dispatcherServlet'
    2018-12-19 17:04:35.198  INFO 709136 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed initialization in 23 ms

What could be the issue here? Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Your log doesnt say anything about errors. please post your controller or upload your app to github

Comment: @georgesvan, its about pointing to login.html as start page, not about controller

Comment: @georgesvan, I'm sorry, I can't upload the app to github :(

Comment: Check your context path, log states the following: `Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http) with context path "" `. Try http://localhost:8080/login.html

Comment: @Rentius2407, I tried with that also, but no result :(

Comment: put your static pages one of the places that mentioned here :https://spring.io/blog/2013/12/19/serving-static-web-content-with-spring-boot , it will be able to access directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your static content is located in a directory other than `/static`, `/public`, `/resources` or `/META-INF/resources`.

Then add property `spring.resources.static-locations` to your `application.properties` to point to the static content.

```
spring.resources.static-locations=classpath:/templates/
```

You will see the following message in the console log:

```
Adding welcome page: class path resource [templates/index.html]
```

Reference documentation

> By default, Spring Boot serves static content from a directory called
>   /static (or /public or /resources or /META-INF/resources) in the
>   classpath
>
> You can also customize the static resource locations by using the
>   spring.resources.static-locations property (replacing the default
>   values with a list of directory locations).

Answer (score 1):

You should read about controllers, if you are learning spring. Try to create a sample controller and when you will run it then go to localhost:8080/ and you should see home.

```
@Controller
public class HomeController
{
    @GetMapping("/")
    public String homeInit() {
        return "home";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With your provided code, launching a GET against your application will return the 404 Spring boot page as you don't handle the relative path '/'

You have to add a Controller class (with @Controller annotation) indicating the request mapping and the request method and render any page you want

Comment: But, why should I create a controller, If I want to open the login.html, just a static page?