# Unable to serve JSP in Spring Boot applications

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc

I have tried several tutorials to serve JSP pages using Spring Boot. They all return a 404 page not found error. 
To overcome the known limitations, I'm using a WAR packaging, with the following dependencies:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
    <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

I have defined the path where JSP pages are in application.properties:

```
spring.mvc.view.prefix= /WEB-INF/jsp/
spring.mvc.view.suffix= .jsp
```

When requesting a JSP page, the following WARN is displayed:

```
WARN 10251 --- [io-8080-exec-11] o.s.w.s.r.ResourceHttpRequestHandler     : Path with "WEB-INF" or "META-INF": [WEB-INF/jsp/hello.jsp]
```

Have JSP been deprecated in Spring Boot 2? Do you have any Spring Boot 2 working example with JSP ?

Comment: Possible duplicate, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53850495/no-webpage-was-found-for-the-web-address-http-localhost8080-in-spring-boot/53850964#53850964

Answer (score 2):

can you please try adding scope in your dependency just like this

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
   <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
   <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm using Intellij IDEA. I found out that we cannot just run the SpringBootApplication main class directly. We need to let the maven do the work.

**Short solution: maven run you application by the command below from your module root directory**

`mvn clean package spring-boot:run`

You can also add a run configuration using Maven so that you don't have to type the command every time.

[image: Configuration]

Some said JSPs folder should be put under src/main/resources/META-INF/resources/WEB-INF/jsp. This indeed solves the spring boot application run problem though, it will fail when you run the application using tomcat. So we still need to keep the structure if we are going to deploy the application to Tomcat.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, I couldn't find any Spring Boot 2 example able to serve JSP pages as they all return a 404 error. As a workaround I have configured the application to be deployed on WildFly, as described in this [tutorial](http://www.mastertheboss.com/jboss-frameworks/spring/spring-boot-hello-world-on-wildfly) and run my application with JSP on WildFly.

Answer (score -1):

If you want example [here it is](http://www.springboottutorial.com/creating-web-application-with-spring-boot).
[This also help you.](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/tree/master/spring-boot-samples/spring-boot-sample-web-jsp)

Comment: Unfortunately I've alread tested the above examples. When changing the parent to be spring boot parent 2.X they all fail with "404 NOT_FOUND"

Comment: It is working for sure, can you post application.properties and pom.xml?